# CSS - Display: Table, fixed width getting a decimal

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having an issue in Chrome where a fixed width div is not displaying properly.  Please see my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ethbcn3/).

I have three nested divs.

```css
.container {
  background: red;
  width: 375px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="display: table; width: 375px; background: red;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 375px; background: blue">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have also given class "container" a fixed width of 375px.  But, in Chrome, the table is actually coming back with a width of 374.4px instead of 375.  As a result, some of the background container div is seen to the right side of the table.  I have tried multiple combinations of table-collapse, box-sizing and table-display properties but can't seem to get this right.  Any ideas?

[image]

Using Chrome: 58.0.3029.81

Comment: I'm using the latest Chrome and the issue is not present in the JSFiddle, nor the inline snippet.

Comment: Same for me. Version 57.0.2987.133 (64-bit)

Comment: Make sure the browser is not zoomed in or out.

Comment: Nope - set to 100% normal view.

Comment: If I zoom in or out it does appear to be 374.xxx other than that unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: That is really really odd.  =/ 
It stays 374.4 no matter what my zoom is, or what width I set my browser window to.

Comment: It is, well try to quit and reopen the browser, try a different value I'd suggest.

Comment: Well, for now, I'm going to assume its an issue isolated to my machine.  Thank you, all, for taking the time to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

use this CSS:

```
table-layout: fixed

<div style="display: table; table-layout:fixed; width: 375px; background: red;">
```